# Is it possible to style the bottom-right drag arrows in a textarea?

Tags: html, css, resize, textarea

I have given the text areas on my page a blue background, and I don't like the way the black arrow/dragger looks with the blue.  Is there any way to change the color (or style in general) of that dragger?

EDIT: I am using Chrome, and have considered the possibility that this is a browser specific thing that I won't be able to change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webkit has a pseudo element for this: `::-webkit-resizer`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/mXNqJ/1/)**

```
::-webkit-resizer{ 
    border: 9px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
}
```